# How to get data from object and put the this data in a linechart component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object, charts

Called object:

[image]

When I call this.state.lineChartData I get the following object(see picture).
The data object looks like this:

> data: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, datasets: Array(0), labels: Array(0)]

When you look to the picture I only need the data [0 till 4] from the array. I need this data for a graph `chart.js`. I don't need the datasets[] and labels[].
How can I get the array data and fill a line graph with this data.
?

```
    <Line
        height={100}
        data={this.state.lineChartData.data}
        options={{
          legend: {
            display: true,
            position: "bottom",
          },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: "test",
            fontSize: 20,
          },
          scales: {
            yAxes: [
              {
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  min: 0,
                  max: 100,
                },
              },
            ],
            xAxes: [
              {
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  min: 0,
                  max: 100,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        }}
      />
    )}
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I only need the data from the array and print it direct into the linechart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you should set your response as state variable differently:

```
fetch('...').then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(resp => {
      this.setState({ lineChartData: resp.data });
  });
```

**edit**

But then you have to map your data to the format recognizable by chart js:

```
this.state.lineChartData.map(item => {
    item.x = item.x.split('T')[1].split('.')[0];
 
    return item;
});
```

That's only an example, but make sure that you supply the data in a number format for both axis. Also, I did not add labels here.

Comment: When I do this I get only the array data(that's good)   but when I want to plot this data in a linechart I get a empty chart.

Comment: `data: [{
    x: 10,
    y: 20
}, {
    x: 15,
    y: 10
}] ` this is a example from chart.js I already get the right format.